# What do the BoundingRect Values mean?

Tags: xml

Today I wrote a custom title for Windows Movie Maker, by creating two text boxes to act as censors (You can see the end product over here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GfBf9J3MrJE).

However, I don't know what the values for BoundingRect mean, I had to go through a lot of trial and error just to get the text boxes in those specific areas. I looked up the syntax, but all it told me was (left, top, width, height). At first, I thought that it mean the position of the box (left, top), and the size (width, height), in terms of the video size, but the numbers don't correspond at all!

What does that mean?

```
<TransitionsAndEffects Version="2.8"> 
<Titles> 
<TitleDLL guid="TFX"> 
<Title name="Censor" guid="Censor" iconid="13"> 
<Param name="Animation" value="TitleMultiTitles" /> 
<Description value="Censor" /> 

<OptimalDurationMultiplier value="4.0" /> 
<Paragraph> 
<BoundingRect value="0.001 0.02 0.32 0.5" /> 

<Param name="BannerType" value="Normal" /> 
</Paragraph> 
<Paragraph> 
<BoundingRect value="0.4 0.1 0.45 0.5" /> 
<Param name="BannerType" value="Normal" /> 
<FontSize value="10.0" /> 
</Paragraph> 
</Title> 
</TitleDLL> 
</Titles> 
</TransitionsAndEffects>
```

Comment: To clarify, the values in this XML are the ones you used for the Youtube video?

Answer (score 0):

They are, most likely, relative units.

So `0.4 0.1 0.45 0.5` translates into:

```
X = 0.4  * Width  of video  
Y = 0.1  * Height of video  
W = 0.45 * Width  of video  
H = 0.5  * Height of video
```

It's also possible that the last 2 values indicate a *bottom* and *right* offset instead of *width* and *height*.

Comment: What do you mean by relative units? Also, these numbers are for a single block. Therefore, there are four numbers per BoundingRect, and eight for two.